# Pandas extractall() - return list, not a MultiLevel index?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a question, which I have a feeling might have already been asked before, but in a different form. Point me to the original if that's the case please.

Anyway, I am playing with Pandas `extractall()` method, and I don't quite like the fact it returns a DataFrame with MultiLevel index `(original index -> 'match' index)` with all found elements listed under `match 0, match 1, match 2 ...`
I would rather prefer if the output was a single indexed DataFrame, with multiple regex search results (if applicable) returned as a list in single cell. Is that possible at the moment?

Here's a visualization of what I have in mind:

**Current output:**

```
                   X
index    match
  0        0      thank
  1        0      thank
           1      thanks
           2      thanking
  2        0      thanked
```

**Desired output**

```
          X
index
  0      thank
  1      [thank, thanks, thanking]
  2      thanked
```

I`ll be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: sample data available?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share it (work-related). Sample I included above captures the general expectation I have towards it.

Comment: You can mock up new data that has the same structure as your work data

Comment: I promise I`ll provide some mock data the next question I might have. Scott's answer below already fixed my problem, so I will not do it this time though. Thank you for your time Dark and Paul H.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.groupby(level=0)['X'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
0                      [thank]
1    [thank, thanks, thanking]
2                    [thanked]
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Comment: Will I be able to merge a few GroupBy objects like that into a single DataFrame, with preserved original index?

Comment: @Greem666 Yes, you can pd.concat and keep indexing.

Comment: That's great. Thank you so much for this quick (and surprisingly easy) fix to my problem. Will have to remember that groupby() method is a good MultiIndex buster next time :)